# Метод полного перебора всех вариантов игры "Реверси"

Tags: алгоритм

Можно ли перебрать все варианты ответных ходов соперника в игре "Реверси", если не с начала, то с середины партии так, чтобы иметь однозначно выигрышный ход, при любом ответе соперника? Как будет выглядеть такой алгоритм если это возможно?

Comment: "Можно ли .." - можно. "Так, чтобы иметь однозначно выигрышный ход .." - врядли, т.к. ходы соперника вы не контролируете. "Как будет выглядеть .." - как полный перебор.

Comment: *Как будет выглядеть такой алгоритм* Минимакс-алгоритм. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81